# Why does an ISFET need a reference electrode?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ph

I'm trying to understand why an ISFET needs a reference electrode. I have looked up several answers online but still dont understand. 
I have drawn out the doping, a MOSFET and the ISFET:

[image: Mosfet Isfet]
In my mind, a change in pH changed the H concentration around the sensing pad which changed the properties of the channel?

Comment: Can you apply a gate voltage to the normal FET with only the + side of a battery? You need a reference, and that is what the reference electrode is for. It completes the circuit.

Comment: Doesn't the accumulation of H+ due to low pH create an electric filed anyhow? I imagine that connecting only to the positive side of a battery would cause some electrons to move into the wire as they are attracted by the excess + charge. ?

Comment: @lukeHappyValley my intuition actually makes me think that I would still see an effect if I connected to only the positive terminal of a battery.